# asp.net only triggered one javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to update multiple Update panel in my web page, I use javascript to run the backend code to update the panel. I found that in the document ready, only the last javascript statement is run which triggered the backend function.

Here is my javascript code.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BoxContent_Button2").click();
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BoxContent_Button3").click();
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_BoxContent_Button1").click();           
    });
```

And here is my backend code.

```
protected void LoadData(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelHideShow.Visible = true;

        Loading();

        PanelHideShow.Visible = false;
        //RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(() => Loading()));
    }

    protected void LoadData2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelHideShow.Visible = true;

        Calculate3(
            Util.CACHE_NAME__ELECTRICITY_CONSUMPTION
            , "kWh"
            , uiElectricityConsumptionUnit
            , uiElectricityConsumption
            , uiElectricityConsumptionYoY
            , uiElectricityConsumptionUpOrDown
            , "Electricity_YOY"
            , companyID
            );

        PanelHideShow.Visible = false;
        //RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(() => Loading()));
    }

    protected void LoadData3(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PanelHideShow.Visible = true;

        Calculate3(
            Util.CACHE_NAME__TOTAL_GHG_EMISSIONS
            , "tCO2e"
            , uiGHGEmissionsYearlyUnit
            , uiGHGEmissionsYearly
            , uiGHGEmissionsYearlyYoY
            , uiGHGEmissionsYearlyUpOrDown
            , "GHG_YOY"
            , companyID
            );

        PanelHideShow.Visible = false;
        //RegisterAsyncTask(new PageAsyncTask(() => Loading()));
    }
```

And here is the aspx.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div style="display: none">
                    <asp:Button ID="BoxContent_Button1" runat="server" Text="Update box Panel" OnClick="LoadData" />
                </div>
                <asp:Panel ID="PanelHideShow" runat="server" Height="262px" Width="350px">
                    <IMG SRC="img/loading2.gif" style="opacity:0.4;filter:alpha(opacity=40);" WIDTH="350px" BORDER="0" ALT="">
                </asp:Panel>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">

                        <div class="ibox-content_v2" style="height: 150px;">
                            <div style="display: inline; height: 100px;">
                                <img src="images/ico_paper.png" width="45" height="45" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-right: 15px;" />
                            </div>
                            <div style="display: inline; height: 100px; float: right; max-width: 70%; min-width: 165px; width: 70%">
                                <span style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; color: #888888">
                                    <asp:HyperLink ID="uiBox1TitleLink" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Total_Paper_Consumption %>" CssClass="TitleLink" /></span>
                                <br />
                                <asp:Label ID="uiBox1Value" runat="server" Style="font-size: 30px; font-weight: 600; color: #002467" />
                                <asp:Label ID="uiBox1Unit" runat="server" Style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; color: #002467" />
                                <br />
                                <span style="float: right; padding-top: 3px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,YOY %>" CssClass="YOYLabel" />
                                    <asp:Image ID="uiBox1UpOrDown" runat="server" Width="6" Height="9" Style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 4px;" ImageUrl="images/ico_arrow_xs_g_up.png" /><asp:Label ID="uiBox1Percentage" runat="server" Style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600;" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,NA %>" /></span>
                            </div>
                            <div id="uiBox1TargetPanel" runat="server" onmouseover="document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_uiBox1Popup').style.visibility = 'visible';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder1_uiBox1Popup').style.visibility = 'hidden';">
                                <asp:Image ID="uiBox1TargetArrow" runat="server" Width="8" Height="14" CssClass="TargetArrow" ImageUrl="images/target_arrow.png" Visible="false" />
                                <div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
                                    <div id="uiBox1TargetGreenLine" runat="server" style="height: 5px; width: 100%; background-color: #FF7373; display: table-cell;"></div>
                                    <div id="uiBox1TargetRedLine" runat="server" style="height: 5px; width: 100%; background-color: #97B879; display: table-cell;"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div id="uiBox1Popup" runat="server" style="float: left; position: relative; top: -50px; visibility: hidden; width: 100%; height: 40px; text-align: center; border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #D2D9E3; background-color: #F2F3F6; font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600; padding-top: 10px;">
                                    <asp:Label ID="uiBox1TargetLabel" runat="server" />: 
                                            <asp:Image ID="uiBox1TargetUpOrDownImage" runat="server" Width="6" Height="9" Style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 4px;" ImageUrl="images/ico_arrow_xs_r_up.png" />
                                    <asp:Label ID="uiBox1TargetValue" runat="server" />%
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel> 


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <div style="display: none">
                                        <asp:Button ID="BoxContent_Button2" runat="server" Text="Update box Panel" OnClick="LoadData2" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-content_v2">
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="images/ico_electricity.png" width="30" height="30" style="margin-right: 15px;" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="uiElectricityConsumption" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                                            <asp:Label ID="uiElectricityConsumptionUnit" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                                            <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; color: #888888;">
                                                <asp:Label ID="uiDashboard2Title" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Electricity_Consumption %>" /></span>
                                            <span style="float: right; padding-top: 3px;">
                                                <asp:Label ID="uiElectricityConsumptionYoYLabel" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,YOY %>" CssClass="YOYLabel" />
                                                <asp:Image ID="uiElectricityConsumptionUpOrDown" runat="server" Width="6" Height="9" Style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 4px;" /><asp:Label ID="uiElectricityConsumptionYoY" runat="server" Style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600;" /></span>
                                            <asp:Label ID="uiDashboard2Label" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Yearly %>" Visible="false" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>


<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                    <div style="display: none">
                                        <asp:Button ID="BoxContent_Button3" runat="server" Text="Update box Panel" OnClick="LoadData3" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="ibox-content_v2">
                                        <img src="images/ico_greenhouse.png" width="30" height="30" style="margin-right: 15px;" />
                                        <asp:Label ID="uiDashboard1Label" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,Yearly %>" Visible="false" />
                                        <asp:Label ID="uiGHGEmissionsYearlyUnit" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                                        <span style="font-size: 18px; font-weight: 600; color: #888888;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="uiDashboard1Title" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,GHG_Emissions %>" /></span>
                                        <span style="float: right; padding-top: 3px;">
                                            <asp:Label ID="uiGHGEmissionsYearlyYoYLabel" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:Resource,YOY %>" CssClass="YOYLabel" />
                                            <asp:Image ID="uiGHGEmissionsYearlyUpOrDown" runat="server" Width="6" Height="9" Style="margin-right: 5px; margin-bottom: 4px;" /><asp:Label ID="uiGHGEmissionsYearlyYoY" runat="server" Style="font-size: 13px; font-weight: 600;" /></span>
                                        <asp:Label ID="uiGHGEmissionsYearly" runat="server" Visible="false" />
                                    </div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Is it always the last function that gets called no matter the order?

Comment: Yes, only the last function gets called

Comment: Clicking an ASP.Net button will cause postback, which is submitting the page.  Only one event is handled because only one event can cause a postback.  You're approaching this all wrong.  If you want to execute server-side code when the page loads then execute it in the page load event handler instead, not in the browser.

Comment: You need to have one trigger, that fires the 3 server side methods instead of having 3 triggers for each method. By the way: The way you try to show/hide the panel PanelHideShow won't work. It'll be hidden all the time as there won't be a partial update on each line of code ^^. You need to handle the visibility of that panel on the client.

Comment: @Schadensbegrenzer Thanks, can I have more reference for me to look into about "there won't be a partial update on each line of code"

Comment: The panel (which in fact is a div) will never be rendered as visible. The server side rendering happens towards the end of the request life cycle. In your `LoadData `method you set the Panel to visible `true`and after that to `false`. So there is no rendering taking place that will set the panel's visibility to true. When the request finishes and the rendering kicks in the panel's visibility is set to false.

Comment: So how can I use one backend function to update all the three update panels?

Comment: You seem to not know the page life-cycle.  The code in your .cs file is executed on the server and the response is sent to the client.  So where you set a panel (div) to visible, do something and then set it to hidden, this all happens *before* anything is sent to the browser.  This looks to me like you want to indicate that something is taking place, and then remove that when some processing is complete (like a "loading" spinner, for example).  Is that correct?

Comment: The entire concept is completely messed up and needs to be revised. So instead of digging into why only last function is getting called you need to learn how request life cycle works. From what I see there is absolutely no need to call on ready function. This all could be perfectly handled in the page load (as @Archer already pointed out.